# AngularJS : How to get ng-repeat directive template before it gets compiled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get the initial html template for the ng-repeat directive that is used inside my custom directive which trancludes nested content. But instead the actual html text that was set inside the directive I get either already compiled ng-repeat directive or simply a comment that looks like the following:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: item in items -->
```

I already asked that question at [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12501), but unfortunately the answer wasn't very clear for me. Is there a way to get ng-repeat directive template before it gets compiled?

Here's a simple example of what I am trying to achieve (and a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oOaEMZDgrGl1JY0iCD2Y?p=info)):

```
app.directive('parent', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    template:'<div ng-transclude></div>',
    transclude: true,
    priority: 1001,
    scope: true,
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      console.log(element.html());
      console.log(element);
    }
  };
});
```

```
<parent>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</parent>
```

Comment: You are right - the comment is an artifact of compilation. What are you actually trying to achieve at the end of the day. There might be an easier approach

Comment: As a result I'd like to have a directive that would enclose ng-repeat and modify it (actually it should replace ng-repeat with a dir-paginate directive).
That's why I'm trying to retrieve the initial ng-repeat, before it gets compiled

Comment: That seems like an odd way of achieving this. Why not just use the correct directive to begin with? But, if you must, you can use `terminal: true` and higher-than-ngRepeat priority and modify the HTML, then start `$compile` on the contents

Comment: There will be some other stuff going under this directive's hood, so I think this is the only way. About making the directive terminal - it seems that it doesn't work that way. I tried to make the outer directive terminal as well as specified the priority higher than the ng-repeat has, but all I've got is <div ng-translcude></div>.

Comment: Look, it's possible to play with and get it working, but your question was about getting the template of `ng-repeat`. So, it's better to ask a new question and specify exact requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-repeat` directive has `transclude: "element", and so, when it is compiled, the entire element is taken out of DOM (in preparation for transclusion) and a comment is left.

So, the first `console.log(element.html())` won't see anything, since the transclusion of your own directive hasn't happened.

But even if you examine the inner HTML at link-time, the `ngRepeat` will have been compiled, but its transclusion would not yet happen; it happens later, when `scope.$watchCollection` of `ngRepeat` fires.

So, the only way to see the content is to preempt the compilation of `ngRepeat`. You can either make your `parent` directive `terminal: true`, examine the contents and manually re-compile.

You can also add a directive that runs on a repeatable element with higher priority than `ngRepeat` and get the contents.

(You could even reuse the `"ngRepeat"` name)

```
app.directive("ngRepeat", function(){
  return {
    require: "?^parent", // optionally require your parent
    priority: 1010,
    compile: function(tElem){
      var template = tElem.html();
      return function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){
         var parentCtrl = ctrls;

         if (!parentCtrl) return;

         // hand it off to the parent controller
         parentCtrl.setTemplate(template);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/oTVFZiaDxElKgt4QX4hV?p=preview)**