# ng-repeat not compiling in test code

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to compile a directive in a jasmine test, and I'm finding that anything in an ng-repeat from my template is not getting rendered in the DOM, regardless of the fact that the data is all present, and other elements are coming through. For example (note there is nothing wrong with the directive as it's beeing used in the app, and I've simplified and omitted irrelevant code for brevity here):

Directive Template:

```
<job-form>
    <input name="Name" ng-model="job.Name">
    <md-list>
        <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in job.items">{{item.Name}}</md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</job-form>
```

Test code snippet, annotated:

```
$scope.myJob = {
    Name: 'My Name', 
    items: [{Name: 'item1'},{Name: 'item2'}]
};
var compiled = $compile('<job-form job="myJob"></job-form>')($scope);
var view = compiled[0];

$scope.$digest();    
var scope = compiled.isolateScope();

document.body.appendChild(view);

//Jasmine tests:
expect(document.querySelector('[name="Name"]').value).toBe('My Name'); 
    // --> pass!

expect(document.querySelectorAll('md-list-item').length).toBe(2);
    // --> fail.  (was 0)

console.log(document.querySelectorAll('md-list-item'));
    // --> Object{length:0}    <-- WHAT GIVES?
```

So I can find all expected elements in the compiled view except the `<md-list-item>`s, even though the data to drive that `ng-repeat` is clearly attached to `scope`. Why is that? What do I need to do to render the repeated items?

Comment: Could you provide plunker?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @FDavidov, no error per se -- just that when I try to find the expected elements, they arent' there -- see what I got in the console.log for the querySelector?

Comment: I would suggest that you first try getting your list through a **static** construct to make sure that your JSON is properly built and used. Then (once you succeed), return to the use of the directive template (I'm not sure I understand why would you need a template though).

Comment: @FDavidov, if I remove the ng-repeat attr and replace `{{item.Name}}` with `{{job.items[0].Name}}`, then it finds one md-list-item, as expected. So it's *definitely* a problem with ng-repeat.

Comment: I don't get it. The template of the job-form directive is using job-form as its root element? So you want a recursive directive calling itself, or what?

Comment: @JBNizet, no. This is in a test. We're simulating putting the element on a page so we can pass items into an instance of the directive.

Comment: How about posting the actual code of the directive? In your question, you're testing the directive `<job-form job="myJob"></job-form><job-form job="myJob"></job-form>`, and you're saying that the template of this `job-form` directive is `<job-form>...</job-form>`. So, the directive is effectively using itself in its template.

Comment: I think I've found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890510/angularjs-how-to-get-ng-repeat-directive-template-before-it-gets-compiled If I add `terminal: true` to the directive this works out and my test finds 2 `<md-list-item>` elements. I still have to see if that messes anything else.

Comment: `terminal: true` is definitely *not* what I want. Back to the drawing board.